# Button instead of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I use a checkbox to overwrite a database entry, it looks something like this:

```
[ ] Overwrite 
[Submit]
```

I want to change the checkbox and submit button to a single button like this:

```
[Overwrite]
```

The Checkbox Overwrite function works like this in js:

```
if(jQuery("#overwrite").prop("checked")){
    data+="&overwrite=on";
}
```

And looks like this in html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="overwrite" name="overwrite"> Overwrite
```

I tried doing following in js to use a button instead of a checkbox:

```
jQuery('#overwrite').click(function(){
    data+="&overwrite=on";
});
```

And in html the button looks like this:

```
<button id="overwrite" name="overwrite" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Overwrite</button>
```

The Button won't work, if I click it, nothing happens. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have some logic on form submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be simply as a toggled button using a simple class for the display like the example below shows :

```js
jQuery('#overwrite').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    
    if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ){
      //data+="&overwrite=on";
      console.log( "overwrite=on" ); 
    }
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="overwrite" name="overwrite" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Overwrite</button>
```

Comment: Your Answer works, however i got an additional problem: if i want to have a submit and an overwrite button, only the submit button works but nothing happens when i click on the overwrite button.

Comment: Hi, try to add the current code as an edit to the OP so we could check it

Comment: made a new question

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = "";
$('#overwrite').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('overwrite')) {
    data += "&overwrite=on";
  }
  
  $(this).toggleClass('overwrite');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="overwrite" name="overwrite" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Overwrite</button>
```